# submit a form with php and provide response to user with ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

im creating a website and id like to know how to allow ajax to submit form data rather than the html action. ive written a php script that may echo one of several results, and based on that echo, have ajax alert what action has been done by the php script.

for example, if php echo is == 1, alert("Your account has been created"); if it echo is == 2, alert("An account is already registered to that email address"); etc etc

ive got some limited experience with ajax from looking at examples and have created a very basic function that will probably be incorrect. just wondering if an ajax expert could fill in the details for me so i can have this functionality. it goes like this:

```
$("#createaccount").submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
    type: POST,
    url: "createaccount2.php",
    data: 
    success: function(server_response){
        if(server_response == 0){
            alert();
        }
        else if(server_response == 1){
            alert();
        }
        else if(server_response == 2){
            alert();
        }
        else if(server_response == 3){
            alert();
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Your question indicates the need for a deeper understanding of the relationship between PHP, javascript and AJAX that should have been researched outside of SO.

Comment: what data are you passing to createaccount2.php?

Comment: "...that will probably be incorrect." Have you actually *tried* it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you need exactly but I see the "data:" is empty, you can use [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to post all input data in your form to your php, like this:

here is a test form:

```
<form id="createaccount">
<input type="text" name="a" id="a">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

here is your javascript part:

```
$("#createaccount").submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
    type: POST,
    url: "createaccount2.php",
    data: $("#createaccount").serialize(),
    success: function(server_response){
        if(server_response == 0){
            alert('HELLO');
        }
        else if(server_response == 1){
            alert('WORLD');
        }
        else if(server_response == 2){
            alert('AAAA');
        }
        else if(server_response == 3){
            alert('zzZzZzZ');
        }

    });
});
```

then in your php you can access the data by the $_POST variable:

```
<?php

$a=$_POST['a'];
if($a=='hello'){
    echo "0";
}elseif($a=='world'){
    echo "1";
}else{
    echo "2";
}

?>
```

if you enter "hello" and submit it to the php, it will echo "0" and display "HELLO"
  (ps: not tested!)